# Pandas update multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to update a couple fields at once - I have two data sources and I'm trying to reconcile them.  I know I could do some ugly merging and then delete columns, but was expecting this code below to work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                  ['D','E','F',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'a','b','d'],
                  [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'d','e','f']], columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','col1_v2','col2_v2','col3_v2'])

print df

 Col1 Col2 Col3 col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
0    A    B    C     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    D    E    F     NaN     NaN     NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN       a       b       d
3  NaN  NaN  NaN       d       e       f

#update 
df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1','Col2', 'Col3']] = df[['col1_v2','col2_v2','col3_v2']]

print df

 Col1 Col2 Col3 col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
0    A    B    C     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    D    E    F     NaN     NaN     NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN       a       b       d
3  NaN  NaN  NaN       d       e       f
```

My desired output would be:

```
 Col1 Col2 Col3 col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
0    A    B    C     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    D    E    F     NaN     NaN     NaN
2    a    b    c       a       b       d
3    d    e    f       d       e       f
```

I'm betting it has to do with updating/setting on a slice, but I always use .loc to update values, just not on multiple columns at once.

I feel like there's an easy way to do this that I'm just missing, any thoughts/suggestions would be welcome!

**Edit to reflect solution below**
Thanks for the comment on the indexes.  However, I have a question about this as it relates to series.  If I wanted to update an individual series in a similar manner, I could do something like this:

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1']] = df['col1_v2']

print df

  Col1 Col2 Col3 col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
0    A    B    C     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    D    E    F     NaN     NaN     NaN
2    a  NaN  NaN       a       b       d
3    d  NaN  NaN       d       e       f
```

Note that I didn't account for the indexes here, I filtered to a 2x1 series and set that equal to a 4x1 series, yet it handled it correctly.  Thoughts?  I'm trying to understand the functionality a bit better of something I've used for a while, but I guess don't have a full grasp of the underlying mechanism/rule

Comment: The right side of that assignment is a `pd.Series` without column information.  That column information has gone into the `name` attribute of the 'pd.Series` object.  When you make the assignment, it is ignoring the alignment of columns and just putting the series you specified in the column you specified.  Try `df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1', 'Col2']] = df['col1_v2']` and see that it just drops that series into both columns specified now.  In order to make an assignment to the correct columns **from** the correct columns, you need to call the columns correctly.  Otherwise, loop.

Comment: I'd also add that if instead you did `df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1']] = df[['col1_v2']]` with double brackets around 'col_v2', this would try to push a dataframe into that column which should put you into the same situation as before.  This further demonstrates the difference between assigning with a series versus a dataframe.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you want to replace

```
print df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1','Col2', 'Col3']]

  Col1 Col2 Col3
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

With:

```
replace_with_this = df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['col1_v2','col2_v2', 'col3_v2']]
print replace_with_this

  col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
2       a       b       d
3       d       e       f
```

Seems reasonable.  However, when you do the assignment, you need to account for index alignment, which includes columns.

So, this should work:

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].isnull(),['Col1','Col2', 'Col3']] = replace_with_this.values

print df

  Col1 Col2 Col3 col1_v2 col2_v2 col3_v2
0    A    B    C     NaN     NaN     NaN
1    D    E    F     NaN     NaN     NaN
2    a    b    d       a       b       d
3    d    e    f       d       e       f
```

I accounted for columns by using `.values` at the end.  This stripped the column information from the `replace_with_this` dataframe and just used the values in the appropriate positions.

Comment: Thanks - added edit above per your solution, thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

In the "take the hill" spirit, I offer the below solution which yields the requested result.

I realize this is not exactly what you are after as I am not slicing the df (in the reasonable - but non functional - way in which you propose).

```
#Does not work when indexing on np.nan, so I fill with some arbitrary value. 
df = df.fillna('AAA')

#mask to determine which rows to update
mask = df['Col1'] == 'AAA'

#dict with key value pairs for columns to be updated
mp = {'Col1':'col1_v2','Col2':'col2_v2','Col3':'col3_v2'}

#update
for k in mp: 
     df.loc[mask,k] = df[mp.get(k)]

#swap back np.nans for the arbitrary values
df = df.replace('AAA',np.nan)
```

Output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    col1_v2     col2_v2     col3_v2
A       B       C       NaN         NaN         NaN
D       E       F       NaN         NaN         NaN
a       b       d       a           b           d
d       e       f       d           e           f
```

The error I get if I do not replace nans is below. I'm going to research exactly where that error stems from.

```
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```