# Pandas replace, to lowercase and else option [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace dataframe values in columns: `Professional Status Activity` and `Professional Status Activity Type` with numbers but before that, I want to be sure each value in map is compared with the lowercase value in thr dataframe and, if there is no value in map, put value = 2.

```
mapping_dict = {
    "Professional Status Activity": {
        "full time employed": 1,
        "pension": 1,
        "student": 2,
        "part time employed": 2,
        "other": 2,
        "unemployed": 3

    },
    "Professional Status Activity Type":{
        "civil servant": 1,
        "judge": 1,
        "army officer": 1,
        "worker": 2,
        "insurance officer": 2,
        "notary": 2,
        "lawyer": 2,
        "consultant": 3,
        "chief l": 3
    }
}

df = df.replace(mapping_dict)
```

So this is the logic I need:
for example if in df column Professional Status Activity first row = `Full Time Employed` then lowercase it and compare it with full time employed in map object so result will be 1 from map.
And if in df column Professional Status Activity first row = `Something not have in map` result will be 2

Comment: Hey, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the question is not completely clear and a minimal complete example would help. But I think you want something like this:

```
df["status"].apply(lambda x: mapping_dict["Professional Status Activity"].get(x.lower(),2))
```

This gows through a column of your dataframe (which I've called `"status"` since you haven't given an example of your actual dataframe) and applies a function on each element. First it calls `.lower()` for the element, which turns a string into its lower-case form. Then it checks for this value in the `"Professional Status Activity"`dict from the `mapping_dict`, using `get()`. Get allows you to specify a default value, which in this case I have set as 2, so if the key is not in the dictionary, it will return 2.

If you want to replace your column with this transformed version, you would do

```
df["status"] = df["status"].apply(lambda x: mapping_dict["Professional Status Activity"].get(x.lower(),2))
```

Comment: It is simple check if value exists if exists return same value from map in other case return 2. So `full time employed` == `Full Time Employed` return 1 from map other case `full time employed` == `Full Employed` it is not equal return 2

Comment: @VladimirDjukic that's what my answer should help you do - using .get() it will return the value from the map if it (the lower case version) is there, otherwise will return 2. Is this not what you need?

Comment: getting error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: @VladimirDjukic can you post an example of what the dataframe you're using looks like? I was assuming the column you were using had strings that looked like "Full Time Employed" etc.

Comment: It works, thanks!!! How fast this can be on example 50000 rows? Also is possible to do replace for both categories in single line?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic it should be very quick, so you might just want to do one after another! But if you want to do mulitple columns at once look e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400246/pandas-update-multiple-columns-at-once (there's a few questions on SO covering this)